# Which one is larger asymptotically?

Tags: algorithms

When $\lg^*n = \min\{i \ge 0: \lg^{(i)}n \le 1\}$, and $\lg$ is the binary logarithm, which one is larger asymptotically?

$\lg(\lg^*n)$ versus $\lg^*(\lg n)$

---

e.g.)

\begin{align}
\lg^*2=1\\ \lg^*4=2\\ \lg^*16=3\\ \lg^*65536=4\\ \lg^*(2^{65536})=5
\end{align}

---

I cannot start how to solve...
This is the problem 3.2-5 in CLRS algorithm textbook.

Comment: What do you denote `lg` exactly? What do you denote $\mathrm{lg}^{(i)}$?

Comment: Ah, $lg = log_2$. I think it is not common. That's why I showed five examples.

Comment: And what is $(i)$ in this context? The iterated function?

Comment: for $n=4$ case, $\lg4 = 2$, $\lg^{2}4 = \lg\lg4 = 1\\$
in this case $\min\{i \ge 0: \lg^{(i)}n \le 1\} = \min\{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...\} = 2$